# How can I go back to the initial view controller in Swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

So I have a login view, after successful login it goes to the first view of a navigation controller, then the user can go deeper to a settings view and then to a logout view. This logout should take the user back to the login view (which is not part of the navigation controller). It works with this code:

```
let loginViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as? LoginViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(loginViewController!, animated: true)
```

But the login view displays the navigation bar at the top, which it shouldn't do, maybe there is something other than `self.navigationController!.pushViewController` that I should be using?

Answer (score 89):

**SWIFT:** You should use an unwind segue.

1. First of all, put the following line in your `FirstViewController`:

   ```
   @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

   }
   ```

   The function actually doesn't have any code inside it.

---

2. Now, go to your storyboard and create an unwind segue for `LogoutViewController` by control-dragging from the yellow button to the Exit button. Like this:

[image: control-dragging in action]

3. Select the unwind segue created for `FirstViewController`.
4. Change the segue identifier:

[image: selected segue]

---

[image: changing the identifier of the segue]

5. Go to the code of `LogoutViewController` and just call the unwind segue normally:

   ```
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToViewController1", sender: self)
   ```

   **Swift 4**

   ```
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToViewController1", sender: self)
   ```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer

Comment: Worked flawlessly the first time, which is very rare to happen in a dev's life. This answer is still valid for Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot

Comment: Perfecto Mondo!

Comment: Im stuck in this problem still... how do you tackle this issue when a user logs in, then you set a token in the NSUserdefaults so he does not have to login again and sometime in the future he decides to logout? When I try this approach the "Login" screen is not anymore in the controller stack because I skip this screen in the app start so I can't Unwind to the login screen. Plz help!

Comment: great solution!

Comment: @MatíasContrerasSelman I am facing the same issue. Plz help if you have solved it

Comment: I had to rethink the way the app starts the first time.Tthe way I did it is to programmatically instantiate all the starting screens EVERY time the app loads but programmatically jumping to the main screen without animation in between when the user token is set. This way the Login Screen is always in the stack of views and I can unwind to it when the user press the "logout" button.

Comment: In Swift4.2 You should use

  @IBAction func prepareForUnwindWithSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        print("Sign Out")
      
    }

Comment: this is the only answer that worked. You could write a blog for it that comes first on a google search.

Answer (score 29):

If you have a Navigation controller, from your your controller use:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Comment: simple , accurate , best

Comment: Definitely the best and simplest answer.

Comment: in swift 4, use self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Answer (score 27):

Look into unwind segueing if you are working with storyboards.

You just need to create unwind option in controller, that you want navigate to:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMe(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){}
```

Then create segue from storyboard.

And when you need to navigate back, just call the `performSegue` method with the unwind segue identifier that you just created.

If you want to do it only from code, than you just can write something like:

```
let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = loginViewController
```

In this case, you will set your app to initial state.

Comment: Worked like a charm, then you very much

Comment: @matt The second variant is better to use. It is much more confident, and you are not creating controller from storyboard.

Answer (score 18):

try it

```
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

This will get you back to the beginning of the application flow.

Updated to **Swift 4** (thanks @javaBeast)

```
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Worked great for me because I had 3 different views and in-between then I had 2 navigation controllers

Comment: After finding 10 other solutions that didnt work for me, this one finally did, thanks! updated for SWIFT 4:         `self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: The only solution which worked for me in SWIFT 5. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

is the best option to go to first controller of navigation controller
and then dismiss the navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to make a segue from one ViewController to another, instead of pushing your ViewController like that.

So first, you need to Ctrl + clic from your first ViewController to your login ViewController, and then in the attribute inspector your give it an Identifier.

Then, all you have to do is this :

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Now, for the navigation bar, I suggest you to remove the navigation controller from the login view, and associate it to your first view. It would remove the navigation bar from your login view.

Comment: I don't believe this works with what he's trying to do... because if you performSegueWithIdentifier, you're adding a new window to the window stacks... not returning to the first view controller..  The best answer would be the answer provided by Allan