# How to unwind to the first view controller on a navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a problem with unwinding my view to login screen. The storyboard structure is as follow:
[Storyboard Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea1t8.png)

The user flow for the app is as follow:
user login on LoginVC-> goes to main tab bar screen by modal segue-> on each tab bar item, I added right bar button on the navigation controller to access profile page, each tab bar item has independent navigation controller to keep the nav controller structure linear. -> once i click profile page button, profile page is presented modally -> when logout button on profile page is clicked, it triggers unwind segue and dismiss view controller

```
func logoutUser(){

        //Networking.logoutUser()
        print("It goes to login")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToLogin", sender: self)
}
```

The unwind segue was implemented on LoginVC on the leftmost VC.I connected unwind segue on the profile screen and call it "unwindToLogin" 
I simply used performSegueWithIdentifier. However, the method does not get called and nothing happen to the view.

Edit 1:
Im wondering since i call profile page modally on tab bar vc, it couldnt find the unwindtologin. 
If i simply use the instantiateviewcontoller to call login, will it clear my view controller stack ?

**Edit 2:**
Sorry, i forgot that when i check if a user is logged in, i use the code below:

```
    if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil) {
        self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController")
    }
```

So actually they can't find the unwind method because the root view is not main login view controller.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I go back to the initial view controller in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052587/how-can-i-go-back-to-the-initial-view-controller-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the unwind segue on every ViewController that you want to call it on.  They can all use the same `@IBAction` destination in the login screen and they can all be called `"unwindToLogin"`.

I see the unwind segue defined on the `MainTabBarController`. In your `UserProfileController`, you need to <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the *view Controller* icon to the *Exit* icon and then select your `@IBAction` in the pop up. Then find that unwind segue in the `UserProfileController` in the *Document Outline* and make its identifier `"unwindToLogin"`.

---

In response to your *Edit 2:*

Since your initial viewController was put into place programmatically, it isn't possible to unwind to the `LoginViewController`.  In this case, 
put the landing `@IBAction` in your `MainTabBarController` and have it set the `self.window?.rootViewController` to the login screen.

Comment: Yes in this case i have called unwindtologin on profile page. It does not get called. Im wondering if xcode does not find the unwindtologim since i presented the profile page modally from a tab bar item

Comment: Could you explain ? @vacawama

Comment: Is your `@IBAction` defined in the login screen VC and did you create an unwind segue from the profile screen itself?

Comment: Yes it is, @IBAction in loginVC and unwind on profile page

Comment: Ok structure photo is above: loginvc -> modal to main tab bar -> tab bar item 1 with nav controller -> right bar button item to profile , present modally -> unwind from profile yo login vc

Comment: Mine works. In your picture, I see the unwind segue defined on the main tab bar controller.  In your profile controller, you need to control-drag from the view controller icon to the exit icon and then select your `@IBAction` in the pop up.  Then find that unwind segue in the profile controller in the document outline and make its identifier `"unwindToLogin"`.

Comment: Put the landing `@IBAction` in your Main Tab Controller and have it set the `self.window?.rootViewController` to the login screen?

Answer (score 3):

Move to any View controller using unwind segue.

***For moves to any view controller when you clicking a button.***

**- (IBAction)unwindToCurrentController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
}**

- Add these above lines to your loginViewController.m file (or) add
  these lines to which view  controller you want to move.
- Actually you want to move to login view controller when clicking a
  button. So,create a button or choose any button for this event.
- Before doing this you want to add the above code to your login view
  controller. Now add action to your button by dragging into **Exit**
  option on ***view controller on the Top***.
- It shows an unwind option unwindToCurrentController.Click that option
  and connect it.

Now Build and run your app. It works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this it Worked for me.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

I use it to dismiss a modal view so that I can return to the originating view.