# How to add action to a programmatically-made button?

Tags: swift, function, button, action

Since I was having issues creating a button via storyboard, I went about initiating a right nav bar button through code - found via this question [How can I go back to the initial view controller in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052587/how-can-i-go-back-to-the-initial-view-controller-in-swift). This code is meant to take me back to my root view controller.

So here is the code as it stands at the moment.

```
 let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "HomeM25.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(getter: UIDynamicBehavior.action))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1

    func button() {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I was under the impression that if I were to change the

```
action: #selector(getter: action)
```

I would be able to create a function following this button initialization like so

```
func action() {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

However, I am greeted with the "Use of local variable 'action' before its declaration'". I do not understand why this interpretation would not perform/why I would have to establish the action variable when its only use is a function name? Any help would be appreciated.

Update 1: Current Code

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "HomeM25.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1

    func action() {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Update 1: Also had to use a different function action to go back to the original view controller.

```
    self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `#selector(action)`. And you can define function within a function. Move `action` outside of the `viewDidLoad` function.  Try this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "HomeM25.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1
}


func action() {
    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You should be doing this in `viewDidLoad` function or any other function. Post complete code.